# What is meant by "Data not originating from the state will never be drafted" in immer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immer.js

I'm confused by [this](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/pitfalls#data-not-originating-from-the-state-will-never-be-drafted) section of the immer docs. I created a simpler example to test the same principle, i.e. to add some new object to the draft data structure and then modify it. Which according to the docs should also modify the original data structure:

```
import { produce } from "immer";

function print(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var todos = [
  { id: 0, done: false },
  { id: 1, done: false }
];

function onReceiveTodo(todo) {
  return produce(todos, draft => {
    draft[1] = todo;
    draft[1].done = true;
  });
}

let nextTodos = onReceiveTodo({ id: 3, done: false });
print(todos);
print(nextTodos);

// [{"id":0,"done":false},{"id":1,"done":false}] // todos
// [{"id":0,"done":false},{"id":3,"done":true}] // nextTodos
```

But this seems to work.

Could someone please explain this pitfall in a bit more detail?

Note: I also tried to use the exact same example that was in the docs, but was confused about what the data structure `todos` is supposed to look like. Since `draft` is bound to the original version of `todos`, this line: `draft.todos[todo.id] = todo` suggests that we have something like `todos = {todos: {0: {done: false}, 1: {done: false},...}`, but `todo.id` suggests that a `todo` object contains the `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about "if you pass and mutate an object inside `produce` it is in fact mutated".

> Could someone please explain this pitfall in a bit more detail?

Basically when you do:

```js
let nextTodos = onReceiveTodo({ id: 3, done: false });
```

The original object can be changed. Consider instead:

```js
const todo = { id: 3, done: false };
let nextTodos = onReceiveTodo(todo);
todo.done; // true, this object was mutated outside of Immer
```